# Django - get file path from client pc

Tags: python, django

I got task to make an opportunity to track if user uploaded file using scanner or USB drive. I find it's possible if I could get file path before uploading it to server. Is it real in Django?

Comment: This is neither possible in Django nor in JavaScript. For security reasons browsers do not allow this, i.e. JavaScript in browser has no access to the File System. https://stackoverflow.com/q/15201071/15239951

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to achieve this in Django as your server does not run on the client machine and thus doesn't have direct access to the file system.